# Posting from AWS-API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple C# Aws Lambda function which succeeds to a test from the Lambda console test but fails with a 502 (Bad Gateway) if called from the API Gateway (which i generated from the Lambda trigger option) and also if I use postman.(this initial function has open access (no security))

```
// request header
    Content-Type: application/json

//  request body
    {
        "userid":22,
        "files":["File1","File2","File3","File4"]
    }
```

The error I get in the logs is:

```
Wed Feb 08 14:14:54 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {
  "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
  "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at blahblahmynamespace.Function.FunctionHandler(ZipRequest input, ILambdaContext context)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ]
}
```

It seems like the posted object is not being passed to the lambda input argument.

Code below

```
// Lambda function
     public LambdaResponse FunctionHandler(ZipRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var logger = context.Logger;
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                if (input == null || input.files.Count == 0)
                {
                    logger.LogLine($"input was null");
                    headers.Add("testheader", "ohdear");
                    return new LambdaResponse { body = "fail", headers = headers, statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.LogLine($"recieved request from user{input?.userid}");
                    logger.LogLine($"recieved {input?.files?.Count} items to zip");
                    headers.Add("testheader", "yeah");
                    return new LambdaResponse { body = "hurrah", headers = headers, statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

//Lambda response/ZipRequest class

```
public class LambdaResponse
{

    public HttpStatusCode statusCode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> headers { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
public class ZipRequest
{
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public IList<string> files { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using Lambda Proxy Integration in API Gateway, the first parameter to your `FunctionHandler` is not the body of your POST, but is another API Gateway-created object, which let's call `LambdaRequest`. Try these changes to your sample code. Add:

```
public class LambdaRequest
{
   public string body { get; set; }
}
```

Change your handler prototype to:

```
public LambdaResponse FunctionHandler(LambdaRequest req, ILambdaContext context)
```

And inside `FunctionHandler` add:

```
ZipRequest input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ZipRequest>(req.Body);
```

The full LambdaRequest object is documented under [Input Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) in the AWS docs, and contains HTTP headers, the HTTP method, the query string, the body, and a few other things.

Comment: Thanks for this example.  Wondering if "Req.Body" should be "req.body"?

Answer (score 24):

This might not have been available when the OP asked the question, but when invoking a Lambda function using the API Gateway, specific response objects are provided.

As previously noted in the documentation [Api Gateway Simple Proxy for Lambda Input Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format), the API Gateway wraps the input arguments in a fairly verbose wrapper. It also expects a similarly verbose response object.

However, it is not necessary to create custom request and response objects. The AWS team provides the [Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/README.md) library, which is also available on NuGet. This library includes `APIGatewayProxyRequest` and `APIGatewayProxyResponse` objects ready-made.

It is still necessary to manually deserialize the `Body` of the request, as it is a string, not a JSON object. I assume this was done for flexibility?

An example function could look like this. It's a modification of the default function provided by the AWS tools:

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var bodyString = request?.Body;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyString))
        {
            dynamic body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyString);

            if (body.input != null)
            {
                body.input = body.input?.ToString().ToUpper();

                return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
                {
                    StatusCode = 200,
                    Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)
                };
            }
        }

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = 200
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also lost a lot of time trying to get a "Path Parameter" passed in on a Get method. For example, if you had a path such as

/appsetting/123

... then you'd have something configured like

[image]

By specifying the resource "appid" as {appid} it tells the API Gateway to capture this as a path variable.

One key discovery I found was that by posting in the body of a POST type action, my Lambda would work. Reading around on some other threads, I then discovered I can transform my path variable into a body of the GET action by:

1. Selecting the GET value (as pictured)
2. Clicking Integration Request
3. Creating a mapping template as shown below

[image]

Now when I test, I'm able to plug in my appid value in only and get the proper result. Hope this helps someone.